running apache built from source sandbox access denied
I have built apache http server from source in macosx monterey. If I run from a logged in user its ok. I have created a launch daemon script in /Library/LaunchDaemons to launch it every 5 seconds with apachectl start because I have the files in USB removable drive.
When launchd tries to start the server I get access denied from the sandboxd while httpd is trying to read files off the USB drive.
How do I get around this ?

I have done the 'Full disk access' on the httpd binary, but it did not work. I am doing it in a alternative way: I set up the mac to have no login prompt and added a apple script exported as an application to the default user login items. The script runs when the machine boots into the users session and runs the daemons- Like that there are no restrictions.

That’s probably because the binary is self-signed. If you were to sign it with a registered code-signing certificate, it might work. Your solution won’t allow the server to bind the usual ports, but apparently that doesn’t matter for your application.

Please go to System Preferences > Privacy & Security > Full Disk Access and add the httpd binary to the allowed list. Then restart the server.
